# ¿Error de rastreo en Urls no existente?

Tags: google-search-console

Error de rastreo en Search Console, Google esta vinculando Urls que no existen y supuestamente están enlazadas desde la pagina principal http://example.com/ pero aquellas Urls no existen.

Hasta me hizo dudar revise todo el código pero no existen aquellas Urls vinculadas.

No entiendo, existirá algún error en su sistema de rastreo.

Comment: Habría sido mejor crear una nueva publicación. El cambio en la pregunta es radical.

Comment: Esta pregunta estará siendo reportada para un roleback a la pregunta original; ya que su edición provoca un cambio de contexto completo; le sugiero a @J. Mick que realice una nueva publicación; con la nueva pregunta.

Comment: Esta pregunta esta bloqueada ya que fue vandalizada y recibio respuestas para la version vandalizada y para la version anterior. Se sugiere que el auto de la publicacion clarifique el sentido de la pregunta, y de ser necesaria se haga una nueva pregunta y se mueva la respuesta a ella

Answer (score 5):

Crearemos las dos cookies y luego leeremos estas, aplicando el idioma seleccionado por el usuario.

### **Creando la cookie con Javascript**

Para crear la cookie con javascript, como quieres que esta cambie cada vez que el usuario cambie el idioma utilizaremos los div de clase "lang:

En cada opción de lenguaje le pasaremos una string que indicara el lenguaje que queremos:

```
<div class="lang" data-value="pt" onclick="Selected-language('pt')">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/299/299693.svg">
  <span class="lang-txt">Português<span> (BR)</span></span>      
</div> 

<div class="lang" data-value="ar" onclick="Selected-language('ar')">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/299/299815.svg">
  <span class="lang-txt">العربية <span> (SA)</span></span>      
</div>
```

Posteriormente crearemos una función mediante javascript, para crear una cookie que identifique el idioma que el usuario seleccione.

```
function Selected-language(language) {}
```

Posteriormente, eliminaremos la antigua cookie definiendo un tiempo de caducidad ya pasado:

```
document.cookie = "language=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;"
```

Una vez tengamos el lenguaje almacenado en una variable y la antigua cookie eliminada, procederemos a crear la cookie. En primer lugar le asignamos un nombre a la cookie:(la string que antes le hemos pasado con onclick)

```
document.cookie = "language="+language;
```

Después, le asignaremos un tiempo de caducidad de la siguiente manera:

```
time += 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 365;
```

De esta manera definiremos el tiempo de caducidad, time almacenara los milisegundos que durara la cookie en este caso:

3600: segundos que tiene una hora.
1000: Multiplicamos por mil ya que la unidad será milisegundos.
24: Las horas que tiene un día.
365: Los días que tiene un año.

Una vez definido el tiempo, se lo asignamos a la cookie de la siguiente manera:

```
time += 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 365;
date.setTime(date.getTime() + time);
expires = date.toUTCString();
document.cookie = "language="+language"; expires="+expires + "; path=/";
```

Finalmente, la función para crear la cookie será la siguiente:

```
function Selected-language(language) {
  document.cookie = "language=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
  time += 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 365;
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + time);
  expires = date.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = "language="+language"; expires="+expires + "; path=/;";
}
```

### **Creando la cookie con PHP**

Para crear la cookie en php lo haremos de la siguiente manera. Deberás, enviar los parámetros a un archivo php. Esto lo puedes hacer de diversas formas. Apoyándote en html o en javascript. Como ya hemos creado la función en javascript para crear la cookie. Aprovecharemos esta función para enviar los parámetros de la cookie a un segundo archivo, le llamaremos createcookie.php.

Modificaremos la función javascript, abriremos en una nueva ventana el archivo php que nos creara la cookie y le pasamos mediante GET el lenguaje seleccionado:

```
 function Selected-language(language) {
  document.cookie = "language=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
  time += 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 365;
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + time);
  expires = date.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = "language="+language"; expires="+expires + "; path=/;";
  window.open("createcookie.php?language="+language);
}
```

Recibiremos en php el resultado de $_GET y crearemos la cookie:

```
<?php
$language=$_GET["language"];
$cookie_name = "language";
setcookie($cookie_name, $language, time() + (3600 * 1000 * 24 * 365), "/");
?>
```

Fíjate que volvemos a trabajar el tiempo con milisegundos. Finalmente debemos cerrar la ventana mediante javascript, asique nuestro archivo php quedaria asi:

```
<?php
$language=$_GET["language"];
$cookie_name = "language";
setcookie($cookie_name, $language, time() + (3600 * 1000 * 24 * 365), "/");

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "window.close();";
echo "</script>";
?>
```

### Aplicando el lenguaje de la cookie

Finalmente solo nos quedara leer la cookie y aplicarle el lenguaje.

Para leer la cookie en php utilizaras:

```
$language=$_COOKIE['language'];
```

Para leer la cookie en javascript:

```
var language = document.cookie;
```

Finalmente, implementas el lenguaje como ya habías hecho:

```
if($language === "es") {
    $website_title = " | Fútbol World Cup";
    $lang = 'es';
    $language = "es";
} else {
    $website_title = " | Soccer World Cup";
    $lang = 'en';
    $language = "en";
}
```

Y en caso que sea el dominio.com sin subdominio, puedes aplicar esto:

```
switch($language){
              
        case "es":
        echo "Contenido en español";
        break;
 }
```

### Validando language

Siempre es necesario validar los valores que pueda modificar el usuario. En este caso como solo pueden ser unas strings específicas, lo podrias hacer mediante un switch:

```
switch(language) {
  case 'pt':
    var language = 'pt';
  break;
  default:
    var language = 'en';                      
  break;
}
```

Como puedes ver, solo me aseguro que la variable del data-value corresponde a uno de los formatos permitidos, y en caso de que no sea así le asignare a language el valor predeterminado.

Comment: Hola @BoredGeek podríamos utilizar código JQUERY y no puro JAVASCRIPT y, en vez de agregar código JAVASCRIPT en las etiquetas HTML nos podríamos manejar por atributos: `data-value`,  o `data-target`

Comment: Hola @J.Mick Por supuesto, y gracias por corregirme, lo unico que pense que no te manejabas en javascript y desde un punto de vista didactico creo que utilizar jquery podria confundir un poco a alguien que nunca ha tocado javascript. De todas maneras ya veo que no es tu caso, pero igual le sirve a alguien mas. Gracias de nuevo por corregirme y haber si cuando tenga tiempo amplio la respuesta con jquery.

Comment: en mi pregunta a la final le puse Javascript pero es porque muchos saben comentar que jQuery es código Javascript :/ pero si amigo es que más estoy familiarizado con JQUERY y creo que tengo uno ya realizado con el cambio de monedas lo voy a buscar

Comment: Esta pregunta estará siendo reportada para un roleback a la pregunta original; ya que su edición provoca un cambio de contexto completo; le sugiero a @J. Mick que realice una nueva publicación; con la nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

La URL `example.com` corresponde a un dominio DNS reservado por el estándar [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606). Ese nombre de dominio no pertenece a nadie ni puede ser vendido a nadie.

El propósito de reservarlo así es poder usarlo en ejemplos de documentación. Ni siquiera es necesario que exista realmente (a día de hoy no tiene IP, aunque no hace tanto sí la tenía y un intento de acceder a ese dominio te llevaba a una página con un mensaje similar al que ahora vemos en [example.org](https://example.org) o [example.net](https://example.net), ambos también reservados por el mismo estándar).

Google no sólo saca sus resultados de rastrear el sitio, sino también de rastrear otros sitios que apunten a él. Ya que `example.com` puede ser usado para ejemplos en la documentación, no sería de extrañar que miles de páginas en internet contengan frases como: "Una ruta puede estar formada por algo como `https://example.com/ruta/valida`". Tal uso del dominio `example.com` es perfectamente legal, y haría que Google indexara la ruta `example.com/ruta/valida` en su motor de búsquedas (con referencia a la página de documentación desde la cual esa ruta es referenciada). De este modo pueden acabar indexados muchos resultados apuntando a rutas que no existen.

Por supuesto esto puede pasar en cualquier otro dominio. Es decir, que una página referencie a otra que realmente no existe. Pero en el dominio `example.com` será mucho más frecuente, por ser precisamente ese dominio el que se puede (y debe) usar para documentar ejemplos que no necesariamente existen en la realidad.

Comment: no debería de indexarla por que la tiene reservada como documentación...